# how deal with atomicity situation

Tags: c++

Hi imagine I have such code:

```
0. void someFunction()
1. { 
2.  ...
3.  if(x>5)
4.    doSmth();
5. 
6.   writeDataToCard(handle, data1);
7. 
8.   writeDataToCard(handle, data2);
9.
10.  incrementDataOnCard(handle, data);
11. }
```

The thing is following. If step 6 & 8 gets executed, and then someone say removes the card - then operation 10 will not be completed successfully. But this will be a bug in my system. Meaning if 6 & 8 are executed then 10 MUST also be executed. How to deal with such situations?

**Quick Summary**: What I mean is say after step 8 someone may remove my physical card, which means that step 10 will never be reached, and that will cause a problem in my system. Namely card will be initialized with incomplete data.

Comment: Preferably, you would write to the card only once, as part of a single transaction.

Comment: Don't execute 6 and 8 unless you have a guarantee that the card won't be removed.

Comment: Use a try/catch to stop the exception from crashing your app? Have the `incrementDataOnCard()` function check if the card exists? How long do the writes take - could you execute these inside a single transaction that's dependent on a flag that monitors the "state of the card"?

Comment: @newfurniturey it's not about a crash, it's about data consistency. Try-catches don't do that.

Comment: Is this program threaded?  As you have it written now, someone WON'T remove the card before step 10.  If you need to worry about that, store the card in an arraylist and check for it's existence before you delete it.

Comment: @zero298: How would the program being single threaded stop me from physically pulling out the card or switching off the machine between steps 8 and 10?

Comment: Assuming you can't force the operations to be atomic, and can't prevent the user from removing the card, you have to make your functions able to detect errors.  In each step, you have to check that handle is still valid, and check the result of your function.  If there's any kind of failure, you have to recover gracefully.  In other words, if 6 or 8 are executed, and 10 isn't, you must be able to roll back 6 or 8 as soon as possible.

Comment: Some form of commit/rollback pattern?

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand you meant a physical card.  I thought you meant a piece of data.

Comment: @Geoffroy The try/catch statement was more of an attempt to ask the OP exactly what he was trying to prevent (he doesn't mention data integrity, nor errors); I also mention transactions as an attempt to get that same question answered - but I fully agree with you.

Comment: How can I make operations be atomic? `someFunction` runs as a separate thread, but the user may take the card out of the reader ANY time. So just writing 6 & 8 data does not make sense, if they were written, 10 must also be written. ps. @moswald: I'm not sure it will be possible to write as part of only single transaction ...

Comment: @dmcr_code Can you stage the data into temporary storage on the machine and, after 6, 8 and 10 have updated said temporary storage you *then* write to the card in a single commit?

Comment: @newfurniturey: I think **single** commit will be hard ...

Comment: @dmcr_code you "cannot" in any way guarantee that step 10 will be performed IF the physical card is removed from your device. Because all operations must have access to said card.

Comment: @Daan Timmer: True, someone can remove the physical card say after step 8 -- which means step 10 will never be reached - which will create a problem for me

Comment: Do you have control over the data format & layout on the card? Or is that fixed? What sort of structure is it, and what updates are possible?

Comment: @Useless: I don't know what you mean exactly. But it is a storage device, I can write/read any data (bytes) I like.

Comment: I mean: what's the relationship between data1 & data2? What are you incrementing? What is the card storing, and what does it mean? In the absence of all that, I've described some general-purpose approaches.

Comment: possible duplicate of [writing of data interrupted by some event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099937/writing-of-data-interrupted-by-some-event)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create some kind of protcol, for instance you write to the card a list of operatons to complete:

1. Step6, Step8, Step10

and as you complete the tasks you remove the entry from the list.

When you reread the data from the disk, you check the list if any entry remains. If it does, the operation did not successfully complete before and you restore a previous state.

Unless you can somehow physically prevent the user from removing the card, there is no other way.

Comment: I don't totally agree for the last part, you can do some copy on write and other methods to actually keep the old data and just "commit" in the end. If you don't commit, the old data is still used, then there is no consistency problem on your card

Comment: @Geoffroy There could still be an ejection while you are writing the new commit. You would still need a way of showing that the commit completed successfully. Unless you can guarantee an atomic write all other methods fail.

Comment: @RedX: How do I know what was the previous state? This means I Must store current state always somewhere else right (on the card)?

Answer (score 2):

If the transaction is interrupted then the card is in the fault state. You have three options:

1. Do nothing. The card is in fault state, and it will remain there. Advise users not to play with the card. Card can be eligible for complete clean or format.
2. Roll back the transaction the next time the card becomes available. You need enough information on the card and/or some central repository to perform the rollback.
3. Complete the transaction the next time the card becomes available. You need enough information on the card and/or some central repository to perform the completion.

In all three cases you need to have a flag on the card denoting a transaction in progress.

Answer (score 0):

More details are required in order to answer this.

However, making some assumption, I will suggest two possible solutions (more are possible...).
I assume the write operations are persistent - hence data written to the card is still there after card is removed-reinserted, and that you are referring to the coherency of the data on the card - not the state of the program performing the function calls.
Also assumed is that the increment method, increments the data already written, and the system must have this operation done in order to guarantee consistency:

1. For each record written, maintain another data element (on the card) that indicates the record's state. This state will be initialized to something (say "WRITING" state) before performing the writeData operation. This state is then set to "WRITTEN" after the incrementData operation is (successfully!) performed.
   When reading from the card - you first check this state and ignore (or delete) the record if its not WRITTEN.
2. Another option will be to maintain two (persistent) counters on the card: one counting the number of records that began writing, the other counts the number of records that ended writing.
   You increment the first before performing the write, and then increment the second after (successfully) performing the incrementData call.
   When later reading from the card, you can easily check if a record is indeed valid, or need to be discarded.
   This option is valid if the written records are somehow ordered or indexed, so you can see which and how many records are valid just by checking the counter. It has the advantage of requiring only two counters for any number of records (compared to 1 state for EACH record in option 1.)

On the host (software) side you then need to check that the card is available prior to beginning the write (don't write if its not there). If after the incrementData op you you detect that the card was removed, you need to be sure to tidy up things (remove unfinished records, update the counters) either once you detect that the card is reinserted, or before doing another write. For this you'll need to maintain state information on the software side.

Again, the type of solution (out of many more) depends on the exact system and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that just:

- Copy data to temporary_data.
- Write to temporary_data.
- Increment temporary_data.
- Rename data to old_data.
- Rename temporary_data to data.
- Delete the old_data.

You will still have a race condition (if a lucky user removes the card) at the two rename steps, but you might restore the data or temporary_data.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what you're incrementing (or why), or how your data is structured (presumably there is some relationship between whatever you're writing with `writeDataToCard` and whatever you're incrementing).

So, while there may be clever techniques specific to your data, we don't have enough to go on. Here are the obvious general-purpose techniques instead:

1. **the simplest thing that could possibly work** - *full-card commit-or-rollback*

   Keep two copies of all the data, the *good* one and the *dirty* one. A single byte at the lowest address is sufficient to say which is the current good one (it's essentially an index into an array of size 2).

   Write your new data into the dirty area, and when that's done, update the index byte (so swapping clean & dirty).

   Either the index is updated and your new data is all good, or the card is pulled out and the previous clean copy is still active.

   **Pro** - it's very simple

   **Con** - you're wasting exactly half your storage space, and you need to write a *complete* new copy to the dirty area when you change *anything*. You haven't given enough information to decide whether this is a problem for you.
2. **... now using less space ...** - *commit-or-rollback smaller subsets*

   if you can't waste 50% of your storage, split your data into independent chunks, and version each of *those* independently. Now you only need enough space to duplicate your largest single chunk, but instead of a simple index you need an offset or pointer for each chunk.

   **Pro** - still fairly simple

   **Con** - you can't handle dependencies between chunks, they have to be isolated
3. **journalling**

   As per RedX's answer, this is used by a lot of filesystems to maintain integrity.

   **Pro** - it's a solid technique, and you can find documentation and reference implementations for existing filesystems

   **Con** - you just wrote a modern filesystem. Is this really what you wanted?

Comment: please see my updated question with more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099937/writing-of-data-interrupted-by-some-event/19100024?noredirect=1#19100024