# writing of data interrupted by some event

Tags: c++

I had this question but some people asked for more info. So I am providing more info.

I have a smart card and a reader. User can remove the card from the reader at *any time*. 
Smart card has different blocks (of 16 byte) and I can write in whichever block I want.

Now I have this function which runs as a thread:

```
3    void function (void *p)
4    {
5        if(smartCardRemoved)
6            doSmth();
7        else
8        {
9            // Smart card is inside the reader
10           writeDataToCard(handle, blockNr, data1);
11            blockNr++; 
12           writeDataToCard(handle, blockNr, data2); 
13           blockNr=12;
14           readDataFromCard(blockNr, credit);
15           credit--;
16           writeDataToCard(cardHandle, blockNr, credit);
        }
    }
```

`data1` and `data2` are basically timestamps and `credit` is credit on the card.
Now the problem is. Say steps 10 and 12 are executed, meaning timestamps are
written to the card. But now, user removes the card from the reader
- this means steps 14,15,16 will not be executed - and that is  a problem for me
because the timestamps were written but credit was not decremented. This as I said
is a problem. So if steps 10 and 12 were executed steps 14, 15, and 16 MUST also be executed. What are the ways to deal with this?

ps. It may not be possible to write everything using single commit, though I need to check.

pps. Now that I think of it, I think I may have similar issues if say step 12 is successful, but step 15 throws exception or returns false. What to do in such case?

I would really appreciate thoughtful and careful answer. Thank you.

Comment: Ultimately the user will be able to interrupt at any step. It sounds like you need to implement some kind of rollback journal mechanism, so that if the write operations are interrupted you can detect this on the next insert and restore the data to its previous state before the half-successful write. This will require some extra storage to store the journal.

Comment: @cdhowie: Could you please elaborate how that rollback mechanism would look like - say with my example? ps. I guess the case with exceptions that I mentioned is a similar issue right?

Comment: You would copy all of the data you are changing to other blocks on the device, then write another block to a "true" state indicating that you are entering a "dirty" state.  Do the write operations and then flip that block to a "false" state to indicate that the write was clean.  When you initially read the device you would check this state block.  If it is "true" then the last write was interrupted and you should copy the data back over the original locations to restore integrity, and then flip the state to "false." If any of these steps are interrupted, the next journal test should fix it.

Comment: @cdhowie: your technique seems nice. So you suggest besides other blocks which will hold copies of all my relevant data, I have a **separate** block where I will store true/false state? This assumes also that the backup operation e.g., during which I will first copy existing data to other blocks, must run successful right? Will something happen if this backup operation is interrupted? (as I see this backup operation must be executed in the first place). ps. Is that it, you think your technique will solve my above mentioned issues?

Comment: Yes, you would need an additional block for the true/false state. The backup operation could be interrupted; this is why you write the "true" (dirty) state at the *end* -- if the operation is interrupted, the state should be false (clean) and the "restore" operation you perform on card insertion should not attempt to use the bad backup data. Yes, this technique should solve your data integrity issue. (It's a similar technique as used by many filesystems and database servers to maintain integrity in case of power loss or device connection failure.)

Comment: Note that instead of using a rollback journal, you can use a "commit" journal. Just write the *new* data to the "backup" blocks instead of the old data. Then, if the actual write is interrupted, a "restore" operation will copy the *new* data over the old. If this is financial data, you probably want to do this instead of reverting to old data.

Comment: @cdhowie: Dear cdhowie, unfortunately I think I can't follow how your new commit journal works :(. Maybe you can also elaborate it as an answer, then I would accept it too. ps. Yes credit is money basically but what is wrong if I use the rollback journal?

Comment: I have created an answer elaborating on this approach.

Comment: @claptrap: If checksum is wrong you mean I should still restore to the previous state right? In that case I would also need to make a copy of the existing data somewhere else right? (in order to restore it then)

Comment: If the checksum is wrong then something really bad happened and the state is indeterminate. This would not be caused by the write being interrupted, rather it would be caused by some hardware malfunction. There is no way to recover from that case automatically, you'd need the data repaired by a human.

Comment: When you say smart card do you mean JavaCard? JavaCard has transactional and session memory, so you can (and should) handle all of this on the card. Moreover, the JavaCard SDK actually comes with an example that handles wallet transactions.

Comment: @Fozi: no this is not java card ...

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Do steps 15, 16 and 17 before the 10 and 12 steps.
> ```

What should that not work. Just swap lines. Do you think it will work?

If you didn't like that. you can reserve a bit for status. set it as one when you start your process and when you finish set it to zero.

next time, you can check that bit and decrease credit before you proceed with the process again.

Comment: About your comment about swapping lines, yes it sounds more ok because this way credit will be correctly deduced but still the timestamps may not be written correctly, which I think still creates an issue. About your second part. Ok, but what if step 10 succeeds but step 12 fails? I will still have timestaps written in an incomplete manner, isn't it?

Comment: I didn't really get what time stamps for. but, can't you just check the status bit next time and if it is 0 you can't re-increase credit. or correct the time stamp don't know. that was the point of the status bit to check it next time.

Comment: is time stamp only to register current time?

Comment: yes time stamp writes current time when function f or those methods where executed

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a commit journal, which is a mechanism used by many filesystems and database servers to ensure data integrity even in the face of unexpected power loss, system crashes, or device connection failures.

The basic idea of a commit journal is that before you write the data to the actual blocks, you write down *what you are about to write* to other blocks.  Then, if the write operation is interrupted you can look at the commit journal and *replay* the complete write operation that was interrupted.  This will bring the data back into a consistent state.

Dedicate N+1 blocks to this on the card, where N is the number of blocks you are changing.  In this case is looks like you are changing five blocks, so you will need six in the journal.  The sixth block is "state" to indicate if the actual write was incomplete.

For example, you might lay out the six journal blocks like this:

```
Journal block: |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |   5   |
Contents:      | B10 | B12 | B15 | B16 | B17 | STATE |
```

The state block can indicate "dirty" or "clean."  Which values you use for these states is not important.  (You can use true or false, for example.  I would suggest making them compile-time constants like `JOURNAL_STATE_DIRTY` and `JOURNAL_STATE_CLEAN` so their meaning is clear.)

The state block should be initialized to "clean" when a card is formatted.

The basic order of operations goes like this:

1. Write the new data to the five journal blocks.
2. Set the state block to dirty.
3. Write the new data to the actual destination blocks (10, 12, 15, 16, 17).
4. Set the state block to clean.

When initializing the card, the very first thing you would do is check if the state is dirty.  If it is, then replay the journal by resuming the write operation at step 3, except in this case you are reading the "new data" from the journal blocks.

If the operation is interrupted before step 2 completes, the state block should be "clean" and no journal replay will be performed. The write will have wholly failed and the card will contain the old data, fully intact.

If the operation is interrupted after step 2 completes, the state block will be "dirty" and the journal will be replayed next time the device is connected. The actual blocks 10, 12, 15, 16, and 17 might be corrupted, but replaying the journal will correct this and the result is that the blocks will have the correct new values after the journal is replayed.

Note that this approach will only work well if **all software that uses the card understands and implements this journal technique.**  If the user removes the card mid-write and takes it to a device that does not know about the journal, it will be using corrupted data.  This is nothing you can do about this.

If you want to be extra-paranoid, dedicate another block to the journal that will contain a checksum of the five data blocks.  This will allow you to detect during the replay step if the journal data is corrupt.  In that case you might inform the user that their card has been corrupted and they need to have it serviced.

Comment: I will check your suggestion tomorrow. Just one thing: I thought this was basically how a rollback journal worked? Or is it commit journal?

Comment: @dmcr_code This is a commit journal. A rollback journal is exactly the same except you write the *old* data to the journal.

Comment: ok. Yes I kinda liked rollback journal initially because I think I got how it would work. Anyway I will give more thought to it tomorrow, and let you know if something. Thanks for help

Comment: @dmcr_code The mechanics of each are identical, if that helps. The difference in outcome is that a commit journal results is the *new* data being written in about 50% of interruptions, where a rollback journal can only ever restore the old data in an interruption.

Comment: I think I still can't follow what you mean. Maybe you assume some prior knowledge that I have, which I don't, so sometimes I find it hard to follow you (although above answer seems quite descriptive). What you mean with above comment? Do you mean sometimes I can't restore the old state if I use the rollback journal?

Comment: also why you thought commit journal is better than rollback one? thanks

Comment: @dmcr_code No, what I mean is that if you are using a rollback journal and the write is interrupted, you will always revert back to the old data.  If you use a commit journal and the write is interrupted, if the interrupt comes after the journal is written you will recover the *new* data.  Since you have a chance to recover the new data with a commit journal, that is why I suggest using a commit journal instead.  Data integrity is maintained in both scenarios, the only question is whether you recover the old data or the new data.

Comment: OK I will consider both of them. But one can't say that either of them are bad or won't satisfy my requirements right?

Comment: Both will satisfy your requirements in that data integrity is achieved.  A commit journal gives you about a 50% chance to complete the write *even if it is interrupted* while a rollback journal gives you a 0% chance to complete the write if it is interrupted.

Comment: OK I see, thanks, again I will look into these tomorrow and let you know if something. Though your approaches seem reasonable to me

Comment: @dmcr_code The easiest way to figure out if this will work for you is desk check.  Use paper and make a box for each cell, and follow the write process I've outlined.  At each step, stop and run the "replay scenario" on another sheet of paper.  See if integrity is maintained.  This will also help you understand the process.

Comment: yes I'll do it that way, just at a first sight it seemed OK to me and that it would work. Thanks again. I also 'trust' you now that it will work :)

Comment: for some reasons I like the rollback journal more :) (so far)

Comment: @dmcr_code Two comments: (1) These two code blocks will actually be in different places completely.  The `if(dirty){` block (including the `if` should be run when the card is inserted, and the second block replaces your current "write new data" block. (2) You only need to do *one* of `copyOriginalDataToJournal()` or `AddNewDataToJournal()`. Use the first one to make a rollback journal, or the second to make a commit journal. Don't use both.

Answer (score 0):

you should implement a circular buffer

data structure will include a bool value, so after the set of instructions are done you can set valid to true at the end before leaving the handling `function`
and cycle through the buffer on each write so you can detect uncompleted access